# Converting a stored UTC time in Oracle 10g to local time

Tags: oracle, datetime, timezone, oracle10g, utc

I have a varchar2(20) column with a value like '2015-01-26T20:29:51Z'.
I successfully convert it to a date with to_date(dEnteredDate,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"')

I wish to convert it to local time by subtracting my SessionTimeZone, currently -07:00 and have a regular date with time, no timezone info.

I do this in MS SQL with;

```
SET @diff = datediff(hh,GetUTCDate(), GetDate());
SET @dlocal = DATEADD(hh, @diff, @UTCDateTime)
```

How can I accomplish the same in Oracle 10g?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
select to_timestamp(dEnteredDate,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"')- interval '7' hour from test_3;
```

Here `- interval '7' hour` will subtract the required time difference and give you the desired result without timezone.

Comment: How do you manage Daylight saving? Change the query twice a year?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
select cast(to_timestamp_TZ(dEnteredDate||' UTC','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z" tzr') at local as date) 
from ...
```